# Why JavaFX WebView not allows fullscreen mode on videos

Tags: java, video, javafx, webview, youtube

> Description

As an example i give `www.youtube.com` which allows you to watch any kind of videos . Below is the minimum code from [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) for displaying a website using using `JavaFX WebView` .

The problems are :

- 1) Not allows to go full screen on any video .
- 2) Can't go on full HD even it is supported by the video.

> Question

**Why that happens ?** I have tried both with the latest `Java 8 Update 131` and `Java 9 update 171`

> Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewSample extends Application {

    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // create scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Browser extends BorderPane {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        //add components
        setCenter(browser);

        // load the home page        
        webEngine.load("https://www.youtube.com");      
    }

    // JavaScript interface object
    public class JavaApp {

        public void exit() {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Cannot go full HD

  Youtube only supports high quality videos on certain versions of Chrome/IE/Safari/Firefox. (I compiled your program with JDK8 and it supports up to 720p.) You can find the below details when clicking "Quality"->"Missing options?"

> Below are some browser and operating system combinations that support
>   YouTube's high-quality video formats:
>
> Google Chrome (all operating systems)
>
> Internet Explorer or Edge on Windows 8.1 or newer
>
> Safari on Mac OS X 10.10 or newer
>
> Firefox on Windows 7 or newer and on Mac OS X 10.10 or newer

- Cannot go fullscreen

  It seems fullscreen mode is not supported by JavaFX WebView because of its own limitations. Here you can find a bit more explanation: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2016-January/018531.html

Comment: Hm , not even Java 9 solves this problem ..... ? , i have one more question if you know it i will not make it a separate one . `Is there any way to set the history of WebEngine?` For example i am trying to add some entries on a `WebEngine` history by default but the observable list is unmodifiable and i get error .

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS I don't see significant changes since 8u131 (new webkit version), so probably not. About setting the WebEngine history, I found from the source code (https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/blob/master/modules/web/src/main/java/javafx/scene/web/WebHistory.java) that you can get the "list" object in line 151 via reflection and change its content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Reflection is killing apps in Java 9 though.